# Update Where Exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I can't see what I'm missing on this sql, the select part works great it pulls 6 rows then I want to update those 6 rows. It updated 10k plus rows which I have to rollback. Anyone see what I'm missing?

```
 UPDATE t_ab SET uom = 3, child = 'WA' 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT q.item, q.config FROM (
 SELECT distinct item, fig FROM t_ab 
 WHERE typ!= 'WA' 
 MINUS
 SELECT distinct item, fig FROM t_ab 
 WHERE typ= 'WA') q, hand h
 WHERE q.item = h.item
 AND h.hand > '0'
 AND q.fig <> '1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query (cleaned up a bit):

```
UPDATE t_ab
    SET uom = 3, child = 'WA' 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT q.item, q.config
                  FROM (SELECT distinct item, fig
                        FROM t_ab 
                        WHERE typ!= 'WA' 
                        MINUS
                        SELECT distinct item, fig
                        FROM t_ab 
                        WHERE typ= 'WA'
                       ) q join
                       hand h
                      on q.item = h.item
                  WHERE h.hand > '0' AND q.fig <> '1'
                 );
```

It will set either all the values in `t_ab` or none of them, based on whether the subquery returns any values or not.

I suspect you want a correlated subquery, perhaps:

```
UPDATE t_ab
    SET uom = 3, child = 'WA' 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT q.item, q.config
                  FROM (SELECT distinct item, config
                        FROM t_ab 
                        WHERE typ!= 'WA' 
                        MINUS
                        SELECT distinct item, config
                        FROM t_ab 
                        WHERE typ= 'WA'
                       ) q join
                       hand h
                       on q.item = h.item
                  WHERE h.hand > '0' AND q.fig <> '1' and
                        q.item = t_ab.item and q.config = t_ab.config
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks it looks good but does the same thing, tries to update 10k rows rather then the 6.

Comment: @Demas . . . The correlation logic may not be correct.  I had to make a guess on what the intention of the the query is.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going to start from scratch. I'm trying to update the missing info that gets pulled with the select portion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is that the condition `WHERE EXISTS` is true for each and every row in `t_ab`. There is **no connection** back to the base table. This is almost always incorrect.

Use instead:

```
UPDATE t_ab AS t
SET    uom = 3
     , child = 'WA' 
FROM (
   SELECT distinct item, fig
   FROM   t_ab 
   WHERE  typ <> 'WA'        -- <> ... standard SQL (!= is accepted, too)

   MINUS
   SELECT distinct item, fig
   FROM   t_ab 
   WHERE  typ = 'WA'
   ) q
JOIN   hand h USING (item)
WHERE  h.hand > '0'
AND    q.fig <> '1'
AND   t.item = q.item
AND   t.fig  = q.fig;
```

This is assuming that you want to update all rows in `t_ab` where `(item, fig)` match the distilled rows in your former `EXISTS` semi-join, now transformed to joining tables.

Key element are the `WHERE` conditions that connect the tables. [More details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html)